# how to open the RDP dialog using Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open a dialog to open an RDP session

Also will I be able to run any of my scripts on a VM.

I wanted to check if the folders exist on the VM.

Comment: Did you go thru the selenium documentation? What does it say? Did you try anything?

Comment: Webdriver is for driving a browser session. I don't understand why you would expect it to open an RDP session (which is done using a completely different Windows executable) or why it would even be necessary to do this in order to test a web-based application.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll be embedding the C# code within the method to handle the windows RDP prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with Selenium. Use MS Ui Automation or any wrapper like [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI) or [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White)